# WSO2 - can we design rest API with swagger editor in WSO2 governance registry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Started working on WSO2 products, not all only few i.e API manager(only for designing rest API's with swagger editor, this is only for Developer portal) and now started working on WSO2 governance registry. Do we have an any option to design my REST API in Governance registry, like how I did in API manager.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Governance Registry is acting as an asset store. So you can store all the swagger definitions, WSDLs, WADLs there.

However, WSO2 Governance Registry doesn't allow you to create or design swagger documents within the product and it is just visualizing imported(designed somewhere else- EX: [SwaggerHub](https://swaggerhub.com/)) Swagger documents.